# Style option element of select list to open it from right to left

Tags: html, css

I have following markup that renders HTML dropdown. On my web page the dropdown is placed at extreme right side of the container. Dropdown contains some lengthy text.

When open in chrome, dropdown opens correctly starting from right towards left, thus showing the lengthiest option clearly. Where in firefox dropdown starts off from left towards right, thus some of the option text goes out of the screen.

Is there any way/css to change this behavior in firefox.

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <select id="select_1" style="width:100px;" name="select_1">
        <option value="-1" selected="selected">Browse options</option>
        <option value="-1">------------------------------------</option>
        <option value="224">Option 1</option>
        <option value="234">Longer title for option 2</option>
        <option value="242">Very long and extensively descriptive title for option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this may help you

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
select {
    direction: rtl;
}
option{
    text-align: left;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, direction has changed. But can we make the arrow appear on right itself while the dropdown opening towards left.

Comment: I did below changes to make it work. That fixed few issues also.                     @-moz-document url-prefix() {
           select {
               direction: rtl;
           }

           option {
               text-align: left;
               direction: ltr;
           }
  }

Comment: clear the default ARROW with this code

  .css-select {
   -moz-appearance:window;
   background-image: url('select_arrow.gif');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: right center;
   padding-right: 20px;
}



****AND ADD THIS HTML ****


<div style="float:right;"><div style="float:right;">&#9660;</div>
    <select id="select_1"  style="width:100px;" name="select_1" class='css-select'>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by setting the select element with a fixed width (100px)

Remove that and the select element will work correctly in all browsers.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8sf5s7jv/1/)

If it's important for you to keep the width, then you can use firefox-only CSS to change the width back to `auto` in Firefox.

**NB**: It is generally frowned upon to rely on hacks like these in production code. Use with caution!

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8sf5s7jv/3/)

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
/* firefox-only CSS..
WARNING: Use at your own risk */

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  select {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="float:right;">
  <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">Browse options</option>
    <option value="-1">------------------------------------</option>
    <option value="224">Option 1</option>
    <option value="234">Longer title for option 2</option>
    <option value="242">Very long and extensively descriptive title for option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes Dan, I am aware of that. But along with select I have no of other controls on the same rows because of which select list has fixed width. Also, the length option text can vary. So, I have to have fixed width to it.

Comment: If you open the page in chrome, you will see how differently it behaves.

Comment: 1) The fixed width has no effect on the option elements, just on the select element. 2) I highly doubt there is an easy and clean way to fix this in firefox - as the ability to style the options 'popup' is largely limited. This looks like a good candidate for a bug to file with mozilla